# Polynomial with Root $\pi+ei$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, transcendental-numbers, algebraic-numbers

How do I find a polynomial with a root of $\pi +ei$ in the reals?

I know how to do this with algebraic numbers, but not transcendental ones like e and $\pi$.

Edit:

I now realize that in the reals, e and π are not actually considered transcendental, but I'm still a bit confused on how to proceed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Two approaches: (1) let $\alpha = \pi +ei$. Then $\alpha + \pi = ei$; now square both sides. (2) If $K/F$ is a quadratic extension and $\alpha \in K \setminus F$, then its minimal polynomial is $(x - \alpha)(x - \overline{\alpha})$ where $\overline{\alpha}$ is the Galois conjugate of $\alpha$ by the nontrivial element of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$.

Comment: I am confused: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number clearly lists both $e$ and $\pi$ as transcendental numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one root is $\pi +e\mathrm i$, then another root must be $\pi-e\mathrm i$.

$$\begin{align} 
x &=\pi \pm e\mathrm i\\
x-\pi &=\pm e\mathrm i\\
(x-\pi)^2 &=-e^2\\
x^2-2\pi x+\pi^2+e^2 &=0\\
 \end{align}$$

Therefore, the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-2\pi x+\pi^2+e^2$ has a root of $\pi+e\mathrm i$.